# selenium cucumber.io get the reports link in Java or Bash (if Bash, still console ouput), so it can be used else where (like slack)

Tags: java, selenium, maven, jvm, cucumber-jvm

When we run tests using Cucumber, we have the option to use an ENV variable and publish the results to cucumber.io, or even without an ENV variable eg:

```
View your Cucumber Report at:                                            
https://reports.cucumber.io/reports/some-uuid 
This report will self-destruct in 24h.                                   
Keep reports forever: https://reports.cucumber.io/profile
```

This works great!!!! But I would like to grab that "some-uuid" and send it to slack (and other places) so others can use it

I can not see a way of getting this with Java using a Hook or Listeners (I think it gets sent back to maven)

I trigger the tests with a bash script, and I was hoping the uuid could be grabbed using something like:

```
mvn test -Dtest=jRunnerMyTest -Dcucumber.filter.tags="$TAGS" ...| tee log.txt
```

However, in this case, within the log.txt, the above does not capture that bit of text containing the reports url (I dont really know why), if it did, I could regex the output and grab that url

I have also tried using --log-file, eg:

```
mvn test --log-file log.txt -Dtest=jRunnerMyTest -Dcucumber.filter.tags="$TAGS" ...
```

In this case, within the log.txt, it DOES capture the uuid, However when the tests run, there is no command output. I really need that command output, since testers use it while running the tests.

How can I get the reports url (https://reports.cucumber.io/reports/some-uuid ) and keep the console output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done this (a long time ago now)
You can just get the response from a text file and strip it out in bash:

```
cmd="mvn test --log-file log.txt -Dtest=x -Dcucumber.filter.tags='"$TAGS"'
reportsUrl=$(grep -hr "reports.cucumber" log.txt | grep -v "profile" | grep -Eo 'http[^ \[U>]+'| sed 's/[^a-z0-9\.\/\-\:-]//g')
testLine=$(grep -hr "Tests run" log.txt | grep -v "FAILURE" | grep -v "Time elapsed")
```